# composer archive create Error: Expected "#", "." or "\"" but "-" found v0.75

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using composer version 0.75v. When I try to create a archive with the following command:

```
composer archive create --sourceType dir --sourceName . -a ./dist/my-network.bna
```

I get this back:

> /Users/fabianhinsenkamp/Documents/businessNetwork
>   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1079
>         else throw err
>              ^
>   ParseException: Expected "#", "." or "\"" but "-" found. Line 14 column 20

Do you know what is the problem? I tried to change the network files but it doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

would have to firstly check that your supported node/npm/docker versions matched these ->

Operating Systems: Ubuntu Linux 14.04 / 16.04 LTS (both 64-bit), or Mac OS 10.12

Docker Engine: Version 17.03 or higher

Docker-Compose: Version 1.8 or higher

Node: 6.x (note version 7 is not supported)

npm: 3.10.x

Note: we are (ie at time of writing) on Hyperledger Composer v0.9.2 - suggest to get this level of Hyperledger Composer (as there have been quite a few changes, since 0.7.5, including syntax in model transactions for example). You can try out your business network definition (ie modeled assets, participants, transactions etc in the online playground https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net/ to verify that everything is OK.